# How to split text into new row after a certain pattern using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a initial table which is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph4IV.png)

I need my table data to appear like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JecVz.png)

Here in column **`<td id="nameOfPeople">`** My data is coming as :

```
Text Text Number Number Text Text Number Number
```

So i need to split to new row after a certain pattern like this:

```
Text Text Number Number 
Text Text Number Number
```

So I have tried like this to split them :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var enteredText = $("#nameOfPeople").html(); //Get the InnerHTML

    var NumOfOccurrences = (enteredText.match(/\s/g) || []).length; //All the occurrences of space (' ')
    var n = 5; //Initial occurrence
    while(n <= NumOfOccurrences) {
        enteredText = enteredText.replace(RegExp("^(?:.*? ){" + n + "}"), function(val){return val.replace(RegExp(' ' + "$"), "<br>")}); //Replace the occurrence
        n = n+ 10; //Increment by 5 to determine next occurrence
    }
    $("#nameOfPeople").html(enteredText); //Replace the InnerHTML
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tapshil" id="" border="2px" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th> <font face="preeti">l;=g+=</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> k|=b=g</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> ldlt</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> eG;f/ dx;'n tyf hl/jfgf</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> cGtMz'Ns</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> d"=c=s/ </font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf dx;'n</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf  </font> </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <!-- put loop here -->
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>11   
            1212231
         </td>
         <td id="nameOfPeople">Arun Lama  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 Amin Shrestha  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
         </td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td id="totalOfAll">36</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Is html table Creation is dynamic? there are multiple <tr>?

Comment: Your approach works fine. What else do you need?

Comment: First, don't use `id="nameOfPeople"` change to `<td class='nameOfPeople'>` and use `$(".nameOfPeople").each(function() { var enteredText = $(this).text(); ... `

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: You've provided a requirement, and a solution - but not provided us with what the problem is.  What specifically are you having difficulty with?  What is not working with the solution that you already have?

Comment: please see the images i have posted above

Comment: yes the table is dynamic and there are multiple tr @Ashu

Comment: at the time of printing you can easily split the string... which language you are using?

Comment: @freedomn-m i have posted my problem , please see the images i have posted

Comment: i am using java @Ashu

Comment: What happens when you run the (fixed) snippet in your question?  Looks to me that it generates an output that matches your "problem".  ergo you already have a solution, so what is the question you're asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex:

> ```
> /(-[0-9]{2})\s+?([a-z]+?)\b/gi
> ```

This says:

> *"First capture group `(`...
>
> Literal hyphen `-`
>
> Class range of one digit `[0-9]`
>
> Qualitative of exactly 2 digits
>
> End of first capture group ...`)`
>
> Meta sequence of one or more space `\s+?`
>
> Second capture group `(`...
>
> Class range of one letter `[a-z]`
>
> Qualitative of one or more (lazy) `+?`
>
> End of second capture group ...`)`
>
> Meta sequence word boundary `\b`
>
> `g`lobal and case `i`nsensitive flags"*

---

So basically it will replace the space between `-2 numbers` and `a word` with a `<br>`. That's all occurrences of said pattern.

Changed ids to classes, jQuery is flexible enough that ids are actually a hinderance.

The following demo:

- Extracts the cell's text with `.text()` method
- Uses the previously mentioned regex with `replace()` to insert a `<br>`
- Finally we render the new htmlString into the cell with `.html()`

---

### Demo

```js
var text = $('.nameOfPeople').text();

var regex = /(-[0-9]{2})\s+?([a-z]+?)\b/gi;

var string = text.replace(regex, '$1<br>$2');

$('.nameOfPeople').html(string);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="tapshil" id="" border="2px" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti">l;=g+=</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> k|=b=g</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> ldlt</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> eG;f/ dx;'n tyf hl/jfgf</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> cGtMz'Ns</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> d"=c=s/ </font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> hDdf dx;'n</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="preeti"> hDdf </font>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- put loop here -->
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>11 1212231
        </td>
        <td class="nameOfPeople">Arun Lama 2070-01-01 2072-01-01 Amin Shrestha 2070-01-01 2072-01-01
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td class="totalOfAll">36</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: in your snippet it is coming fine but in my code it is generated by JSTL (java).. so i think <br> is not appearing. i want to clear that <td> so i tried $(".tapshil tbody tr td .nameOfPeople").text(''); and want to replace by your code but <td> is not being empty

Comment: @AshwinKarki Did you change `id="nameOfPeople"` to `class="nameOfPeople"`? If you haven't then `$("#nameOfPeople")` should work.

Comment: yes i have changed but i have thought to clear my data first and will be replaced by your code.I tried to clear that <td> after page is loaded and added $(".tapshil tbody tr td .nameOfPeople").text('');  inside script but it is not clearing

Comment: it feels so bad to see output not coming as u have worked so hard :(

Comment: Are you using single quotes or one double quote in `.text('')`?  can't tell... Wrap your code with backticks: ``` it'll format it into monospace font, it'll be easier for my old eyes.

Comment: $(".tapshil tbody tr td .nameOfPeople").text('   ');

Comment: hello sir,i think i have seen my one fault: initially in table it is appearing as  Text_text__number_number where to illustate you: _  is single space and __is double space

Comment: Ok updated answer. Now it'll match one or more spaces.

Comment: thank you for the effort new to SO plz upvote my question

Comment: My answer didn't work? I noticed you upvoted then unvoted.

Comment: so sry, i had opened SO in 3-4 tabs and once i had upvoted your ans where as in  other page were not refreshed so dont know it happened by some kind of accident.Really sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Jquery you should try generating the table with the following html mark-up:

```
<td id="nameOfPeople">Arun Lama  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 <br> Amin Shrestha  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 </td>
```

Notice that i have added a `<br>` tag to break the line into 2
You can use it similarly on your first column too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="nameOfPeople"` instead of `id="nameOfPeople".`

Use Below js which will add `"<br>"` after every 4 words from string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        alert("inside");
        $( ".nameOfPeople" ).each(function() {
            var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
             html = html.slice(0,4).join(" ") + "<br />" + html.slice(4).join(" ");
             $(this).html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the output is coming as : Arun lama 2070-01-01 <br>
2072-01-01 Amin Shrestha  2070-01-01 2072-01-01

Comment: hello sir,i think i have seen my one fault: initially in table it is appearing as Text_text__number_number where to illustate you: _ is single space and __is double space

Comment: @AshwinKarki yes there is one extra space

Comment: thank you for the effort new to SO plz upvote my question :)